# Editing BuddyPress email body link in the user activation email link

Tags: buddypress

How can I edit the [wordpress@example.com] shown as part of title email of user registration? I want to edit the [wordpess@example.com] to a custom one by removing the "wordpress".

Thanks for your kind effort.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's a WordPress related thing, not actually a BuddyPress. So below is the code for that:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'change_mail_from');
function change_mail_from($from_email){
    $from_email = 'support@example.com';
    return $from_email;
}

add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'change_mail_from_name');
function change_mail_from_name($from_name){
    $from_name = 'Support Team';
    return $from_name;
}
```

Just modify `$from_email` and `$from_name` variable according to your needs and insert in either your plugin or `functions.php` of a theme.

Comment: Thanks a million slaFFIK! I actually used this now I will go change it; function change_activation_email_body($message) {
        return __( "Change Activate Email body", 'buddypress' );
    }
    add_filter('bp_core_activation_signup_user_notification_subject', 'change_activation_email_body');